# How can I connect my ionic app with MAMP MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, ionic-framework, mamp

I am using ionic and php to build my app. I am trying to connect my ionic app with MAMP MYSQL service. Here is my config.php file:

```
<?php
  define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:3306');
  define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'myapp');
  $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

But it seems it doesn't work well. Can anyone give me some suggestion on it?

Error Message:

[image]

My iosServer structure :

[image]

Comment: What doesn't seem to work well? Can you give an error message it gave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PHP is must, I would recommend looking at [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) which is made for creating APIs.Some other solutions that fits here (probably better than PHP & MySQL for this purpose) are [Mongo](https://www.mongodb.org/) + [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/index.html) or [ParseSDK for JavaScript](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide) are something to look at as well. I would recommend Parse since it is very easy to get started with and remove a lot of back end headaches.

Sample example using ionic to access API:

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
    $http.get('API_URL')
        .then(
            function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $scope.data = data;
                // JSON data returned as response
            },
            function(err){
                console.log(err);
                $scope.err = err;
                // when error occurs
            }
        );
});
```

**View:**

```
<ion-content ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div> {{ data }} {{ err }} </div>
</ion-content>
```

[Example](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/a-simple-weather-forecast-app-with-ionic-framework-and-forecastio/107) of usage of JSON data.